# Netstat shows very large number of connected IPs

Tags: networking, windows-10, security, ip, remote-access

I just ran `netstat` on my computer and found a large number of remote IPs connected, at least one of which shows as being from a website which when I googled was listed as a known scam site -- a site which I have never been to myself. What I would like to be able to do is to:

1. Kick off all non-essential connections right now
2. Work out a way to filter and monitor connections so this doesn't happen again

It would be brilliant if people could advise me how to deal with the issue which allows me to retain control and visibility with regard to IPs connecting to my machine on an ongoing basis.

(I am currently using Windows 10)

Listings as follows:

```
C:\Sites>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1542         Metatron-Prime:5354    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1543         Metatron-Prime:5354    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1561         Metatron-Prime:27015   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         Metatron-Prime:1542    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         Metatron-Prime:1543    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        Metatron-Prime:1561    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:12324    104.244.42.193:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:12506    ec2-23-23-191-237:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:15924    xx-fbcdn-shv-01-lhr3:https  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:15937    a23-65-38-233:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:33472    a23-209-195-156:https  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:34696    157.55.56.147:40036    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:34701    msnbot-191-232-139-114:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:34755    wb-in-f188:5228        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:34773    ec2-52-72-45-37:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:34774    ec2-52-72-196-252:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:34930    91.190.216.66:12350    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:35876    207.46.155.236:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:36652    191.232.139.13:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:38499    snt405-m:https         CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:38500    snt405-m:https         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:38937    lhr26s05-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:39256    lhr26s05-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:39314    ec2-54-84-31-86:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:39315    ec2-52-201-207-113:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:39355    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:39765    lhr26s02-in-f3:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40171    87.237.19.50:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40278    fastsuppodt:https      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40279    fastsuppodt:https      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40285    fastsuppodt:https      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40286    fastsuppodt:https      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40290    67.217.67.200:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40291    67.217.67.200:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40292    67.217.67.200:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40348    65.55.44.109:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40569    ec2-54-243-247-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40580    lhr26s05-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40583    lhr26s05-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40653    68.232.35.111:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40654    68.232.35.111:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40655    68.232.35.111:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40656    68.232.35.111:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40657    68.232.35.111:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40658    68.232.35.111:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40659    a23-209-200-231:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40663    lhr26s05-in-f16:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40665    lhr25s02-in-f8:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40667    a184-30-97-91:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40671    lhr26s05-in-f6:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40674    lhr25s02-in-f110:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40679    wk-in-f155:https       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40682    104.25.26.12:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40684    185.31.19.193:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40824    ec2-52-86-69-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40825    ec2-52-86-69-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40828    ec2-52-86-69-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40829    ec2-52-86-69-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40830    ec2-52-86-69-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40831    ec2-52-86-69-94:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40834    lhr25s02-in-f110:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40931    lhr26s05-in-f5:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40950    151.80.207.141:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40954    lhr25s09-in-f2:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40956    lhr26s01-in-f10:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:40959    host04:http            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41000    lhr25s09-in-f2:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41001    lhr25s09-in-f2:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41004    wb-in-f95:https        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41005    a23-55-122-180:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41006    ec2-54-173-23-49:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41009    lhr26s02-in-f162:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41010    ec2-54-247-115-216:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41011    ec2-176-34-115-222:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41014    a104-65-26-123:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41015    ec2-54-175-1-116:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41016    server-52-85-59-161:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41028    54.239.25.208:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41097    157.56.148.23:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41105    93.184.221.200:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41106    a23-65-46-202:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41107    a104-65-20-192:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41108    a104-65-20-192:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41115    a104-65-20-192:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41120    134.170.188.139:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41121    93.184.221.200:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41124    a104-65-29-50:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41126    a23-195-66-72:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41127    a23-43-75-27:http      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41128    40.114.241.141:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41164    ec2-54-229-90-9:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41201    a-0001:https           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.122:41210    server-54-239-164-192:https  ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: And you ran which command exactly?

Comment: Tried closing down browser windows and such but there's still just as many, and even some new ones.

Comment: Restart and do a `netstat` again **before** opening a browser.

Comment: Restarted and a bunch are still connected... still not feeling great about having a boat-load of TCP connections established to my PC and not knowing what they are. A `whois` lookup doesn't really help either; beyond anything else different apps and websites seem to give different information; and even if I could trace the location to a person or business accurately, what I'd really want to know is what the connection is doing and what caused the connection... Hhhmmmmmmm. Maybe I should do another full Linux install with a barebones system but even then...

Comment: Adding a entry to your hosts file that sets `fastsuppodt.com` and `fastsupport.com` to 127.0.0.1 should prevent any "malicious" users from accessing your computer if you happen to have Citrix software installed on your system without your knowlege.  Browser connections are TCP connections, so having TCP being established, is actually normal.  You mention you restarted, but don't mention, if that same entry was present.

Comment: Hhhmmmm, does fastsupport come bundled with something Citrix created perhaps? I don't recall being asked for permissions allowing it to remote connect anything in the background without my consent...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen - Go to the chat.  You have not supplied enough information for me to submit an answer.

Comment: `fastsuppodt.com` is a non-existent domain.

Comment: Try running [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) - it will show show a lot more information about the connections - like what process is making the connections you are worried about.

Comment: [GoToAssist](https://www.fastsupport.com/) reports itself as `fastsuupport.com`. Weird.

Comment: Citrix appear to own a whole bunch of mispelt names including `faastsupport.com`, `fastsuupport.com` but **not** `fastsuppodt.com`

Comment: You are not going to like this : If your computer is infected, run antivirus scans. Or safer : Reformat the disk and reinstall Windows 10. Then install protections.

Comment: @harrymc that's not going to give me the level of visibility or the specific control over my system that I want. I'm not interested in having these things handled for me. I want to learn how to start doing these things for myself, hence the specifics of my question.

Comment: If your computer is infected, nobody can tell you what to do, because nobody really knows. You can only restart from scratch, but this time with protections - there we can help you.

Comment: @DavidPostill developers _do_ have a certain fancy for typos... ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kick off all non-essential connections right now

Nirsoft Currports should be able to do the job for you. It displays current open TCP/UDP connections/ports, and allows you to kill the connection. You can find it on the Nirsoft website.

> Work out a way to filter and monitor connections so this doesn't
>   happen again

Windows Advanced firewall should be sufficient for filtering network activity, and id suggest using it in combination with the applications below.

For monitoring your network activity id suggest using a combination of Wireshare and Process Monitor. Both tools are very powerful and are filled with information. If you have never used Wireshark before, id suggest brosing their community and documentation, otherwise it could get a bit overwhelming with all the information youre presented with.

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)

**EDIT:**

As **@jveazey** suggested in comments below, ill add TCPView to the list. It effectively combines the function of Currports and Proccess Monitor in this case.

[TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx)

Comment: I recommend adding TCPView (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) to that list.

Answer (score 2):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is a tool that may suit your purposes.  I install it on all my machines.  Click on the "Network" tab and kill any unwanted connections from there.  And as was suggested, you can add any unwanted domains to your HOSTS file in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Comment: I'll check this one out in a bit. Looks interesting. Though of course I maintain a healthy paranoia about security related .exe files...

Comment: Naturally.  PH is an open-source project, and they've been around for a bit, but by all means, look into them until you feel comfortable trying it out.  They have a portable executable, also, if you want to just get your feet wet.